# MongoDB migration with mongomirror

Tags: migration, mongodb, mirroring

We are trying to migrate our databases to atlas solution according to [documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongomirror/).

Our replicaset config:

```
replication:
  oplogSizeMB: 1
  replSetName: rs0
```

But we are getting such error:

> 2017-09-06T12:47:00.956+0100    Tailing the oplog
>   2017-09-06T12:47:00.976+0100    Waiting for new oplog entries to
>   apply. 2017-09-06T12:47:00.977+0100    Failed: error while tailing the
>   oplog on the source: Checkpoint not available in oplog! expected:
>   6462593017768312852; got: 6462630134875684867

What could be wrong? Why it is failing?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you've set your oplog size to 1 MB. The [default oplog size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#oplog-size) is typically 5% of free disk space with a minimum size of 50MB and a maximum of 50GB. If you are actively writing to this replica set, your oplog is going to roll over every 1MB and anything following the oplog (`mongomirror`, secondaries in the same replica set, ... ) is unlikely to be able to stay in sync.

Comment: Can you confirm the current oplog size with `rs.printReplicationInfo()` in the `mongo` shell?  I suggest you [change the size of the oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/) to something closer to the default.

Comment: Yes it was 1M. I changed it, and started mongomirror again, will let you know if it helpd.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions from comments solved my problem. Removing oplogSizeMB option from config helpd.

NOTE: removing/changeing this value not take effect without additional steps:

1. remove replicaSet ALL options from config.
2. restart DB
3. drop "local" db (containing replicaSet configuration)
4. Add replicaSet configuration to DB
5. restart database
6. initiate replicaSet with rs.initiate() again
7. new values will be seted up

Comment: This works well for a single-node cluster, but refer to the official docs for the proper way to deal with multiple members: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/
Note that this can be one online in 3.6+, but prior versions are a bit more involved.